# Invalid EFI file path

Tags: grub2, windows-7, uefi, grub-efi

i've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my new laptop ( with Win7 64bit pre installed ) in EFI mode and now i can't load Win7 anymore ( Ubuntu just loads fine from grub ).
When i select the Windows 7 entry in the grub menu, i get this error:

```
Invalid EFI file path
```

The grub.cfg entry ( generated by boot-repair ) is:

```
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda3)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,gpt3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root B8449665449625E2
    chainloader +1
}
```

This is the parted output :

```
GNU Parted 2.3
Viene usato /dev/sda
Benvenuti in GNU Parted. Digitare "help" per l'elenco dei comandi.
(parted) print list
Modello: ATA ST9500325AS (scsi)
Disco /dev/sda: 500GB
Dimensione del settore (logica/fisica): 512B/512B
Tabella delle partizioni: gpt

Numero  Inizio  Fine   Dimensione  File system  Nome                  Flag
 5      1049kB  106MB  105MB       fat32                              avvio
 3      345MB   200GB  200GB       ntfs         Basic data partition
 1      200GB   200GB  1049kB                                         bios_grub
 2      200GB   496GB  296GB       ext4
 4      496GB   500GB  4172MB
```

The boot EFI partition, mounted as

```
/dev/sda5 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw) )
```

has the following files ( excluding the grub folder and other files on the boot root ) :

```
./efi
./efi/efi
./efi/efi/boot
./efi/efi/boot/bootx64.efi
./efi/efi/ubuntu
./efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
./efi/efi/Microsoft
./efi/efi/Microsoft/Boot
./efi/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi.grb
./efi/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
./efi/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootx64.efi.grb
./efi/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootx64.efi
```

How can i fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Your GRUB entry for Windows is appropriate for a BIOS-mode boot, but not for an EFI-mode boot. This is a GRUB bug. You can try replacing the entry with something like the following:

```
menuentry "Windows 7" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod chain
    set root='(hd0,gpt5)'
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

I make no guarantees that this will work, but it might. If it does, add that entry to `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` so that it will be created again whenever Ubuntu updates its GRUB configuration.

Another option is to use a different boot manager in addition to or instead of GRUB. [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) for instance, will auto-detect both Windows and GRUB; and if you're using 3.3.0 or later kernels (as shipped with Ubuntu 12.10, but not with Ubuntu 12.04), you can boot Linux directly with rEFInd, bypassing GRUB entirely. [gummiboot](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/gummiboot) is another option with similar boot capabilities, but it requires more manual maintenance if you wanted to boot Linux directly with gummiboot.

Comment: Using that menu entry, sends me from grub to a black screen and then back to grub again :(

Comment: refind gives me the windows option by if i choose it grub menu is opened O.o

Comment: That sounds like Ubuntu has renamed the Windows boot loader and installed itself in its place! My hunch is the `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi.grb` file on the ESP is the real Windows boot loader, so renaming `bootmgfw.efi` to something else and then renaming `bootmgfw.efi.grb` back to bootmgfw.efi will fix it. You can check the file sizes of these files and of `EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi` to verify this, or use `diff` to compare them. FWIW, Ubuntu's developers might have done this to work around bugs in some EFI implementations, but it's rather naughty of them, if so!

Comment: On my laptop I had to `set root=(hd0,gpt1)` because that is where my DELL keeps its EFI partition.

Comment: Don't be fooled into thinking because the tab autocomplete can see the gpt labels, etc. that it will use them to boot. The `insmod part_gpt` is needed. If you're here for a non-Windows GRUB chainloading fix and your path is correct, that is your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i've solved formatting and reinstalling everything from scratch ... basically ( don't know why ) grub had overwritten the windows 7 loader, that was the problem.

Comment: Ubuntu used to have a bug where it would wipe the ESP, but I thought that was fixed. Perhaps it's lingering under some circumstances. :-( A tip: Back up your entire ESP. That way if something weird happens, you can restore it in the future. (EFI doesn't rely on boot sector code, so a file-level backup works fine.)

Answer (score 1):

As of today, in Xubuntu 22.04, I have been using the information provided above for my laptop using UEFI. However now I have had to add the location of the ESP partition to the chainloader line.

This is what my working configuration looks like now:

```
menuentry "Windows 10" {
insmod part_gpt
insmod chain
set root='(hd0,gpt4)'
chainloader (hd0,gpt2)/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

}

Also, the file in which I have had to insert it in order for it to work, is the file " custom " located under /etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts.

One more annoyance was occurring at the same time : several sets of entries had appeared in the Grub boot stanza for the same Xubuntu install (not several installs). I have used grub-customizer, installed from its PPA, to fix it.

It seemed to me that the different entries had been generated through several proxy files located under /etc/grub.d, probably 10_linux_proxy, 31_linux_proxy, and 41_linux_proxy.

I would not dare change the default settings manually, of course.

Comment: I forgot to explain why I had to add the path to the ESP partition in the chainloader line : the boot failed with an error stating that the said file could not be found. I tried this as a guess as good as another, and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

This an Update to the Answer for this question -- Ubuntu 22.04 MATE either ignores or otherwise over wrote my Win 10 Pro boot ... a quick jump to Ventoy and loading the Win10 ISO installer and then select Repair Boot fixes the issue ... whether it comes back after a kernel update remains to be seen :P

Thx/Sx