# Invaild EFI file path - can't boot into windows 8

Tags: installation, grub2, windows-8, uefi

I have installed Ubuntu on my lenovo ideapad Y580 ( with win 8)

Ubuntu works great, but when I use grub to select windows ,

```
error can't find commend 'drivemap'
invaild  EFI file path
```

what does it mean? how do I fix this and use windows 8?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem... I used Boot-Repair, that helped a lot

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair
```

Then run Boot-Repair and you should be able to start Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick search and came across this:

[Invalid EFI file path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216215/invalid-efi-file-path)

I hope it helps.